# How do define source root in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In Webstorm I can easily mark folders as source root or some other stuff.
But source root is the most important when ctrl clicking components in your code.

Is there a simular way of doing this in VS Code? It doesnt understand my js imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file `jsconfig.json` at the root of you project with the following content (replace src with relative source root):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

For further details: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14907#issuecomment-306853768

Comment: what about multiple folders?